# Unused but named variable in JS

Tags: javascript, variables, naming

I started recently learning JS and currently, I have a question of is a good practice to use a named but unused variable for example I'm using the .filter() function(or property since arrays are an object, I don't know what is the right term here so bear with me :D) and want to denote that I don't use the element but only the index of the element, but since I use the element variable can I name it as *element or element* or is there some syntax where I can denote that this exact variable is not used anywhere, ofc except changing the variable name or saying unused. It's a question that arose to me so it's not anything serious.

```
    arr.filter((element_, index) => index % 2 !== 0).map((element) => element * 2).reverse())
```

That above is the code I was describing, I want to denote for myself that the first piece in the .filter() arguments is the element and the second piece is the index, so I use only the index. Also, I know that most of you will say that it's a bad practice to do such one-liners, I'm just experimenting. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's probably rather subjective. Common practices are to just use an underscore (`_`) or prefix the variable name with an underscore (so almost what you have). But in the end, as long as you understand your code it should be fine :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably call the first argument just `_`, I've seen people do that. However the javascript interpreter sees no difference.

You can also ommit the `!== 0` and [it will work just the same](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

```js
arr
    .filter( (_, index) => index % 2 )
    .map( (element) => element * 2 ) 
    .reverse()
```

Answer (score 1):

Name your arguments as you please, I personally use `value` as convention.

```js
arr
.filter((value, index) => index % 2 !== 0)
.map((value) => value * 2)
.reverse())
```

Its for your own reference at later stage.